# Passing data between activities in onPause

Tags: java, android

i am facing trouble in passing data in activity's onpause() method.when user clicks a button in one activity, 2nd activity starts.in 1st activity's onPasue method i want to pass some data to other activity.i use intent.putExtra() to save data in onpause().in 2nd activity i use bundle.getString() to retrieve data.below is my code

```
 public class FirstActivity extends Activity {

Intent intent;
Button b;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tola_calculation);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    intent = new Intent(Tola_calculation.this, Kaat_calculation.class);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    intent.putExtra("key", "i am value");
}}
```

and

```
public class secondActivity extends Activity {
 int value;
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_kaat_calculation);
    Bundle extras=new Bundle();
    Intent intent=getIntent();
    extras=intent.getExtras();
    if (extras!=null) {
        String value = extras.getString("key");
        Toast.makeText(Kaat_calculation.this,value,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(Kaat_calculation.this,"null problem",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


}}
```

problem is in 2nd activity intent.getExtras() returns null first time.i press back button 1st activity resumes.then i click  again to go to 2nd activity.this time data is retrieved and intent.getextras() does not return  null.can somebody explain this strange behaviour.or i am doing something strange as i am new to android programming.i hope i am able to clearly explain problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because your 2nd `Activity` is created *before* the 1st `Activity` calls `onPause()`.

Solution: put your extra inside the `onClick()` callback. In other words (as the other answers suggest) you need to attach data to the `Intent` before calling `startActivity()` with that `Intent`.

> In 1st `Activity`'s `onPause()` method I want to pass some data to
>   other `Activity`

There's absolutely no need to do so because your 1st `Activity` is guaranteed to call `onPause()` as soon as your 2nd `Activity` becomes visible. So you already know at this point that your 1st `Activity` has called `onPause()`.

Consult the [official docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) on Activity lifecycle for more details.

Comment: thanks for every one,s reply.putting it inside onClick already worked.but i needed to send data when an activity is going to pause state due to this button click or some other reason.i was wondering what is reason behind this behavior.i got answer thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should add data to Intent before you start the new activity. So this row

```
intent.putExtra("key", "i am value");
```

Should go before

```
startActivity(intent);
```

All in all, right code

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity {

Intent intent;
Button b;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tola_calculation);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    intent = new Intent(Tola_calculation.this, Kaat_calculation.class);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            intent.putExtra("key", "i am value");
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**It's NOT working the first time because** when you are calling `startActivity` the extra is not set yet. Activity #2 starts before `onPause` is called.

**It is working the second time because** you made the intent variable *an instance variable* and you are not calling `finish()` after `startActivity()` call. That makes your first activity instance stay alive. The second time you launch the activity #2 the intent instance is already there and it already has the extra in it.

**Solution:** you should put the extra right before calling `startActivity()` and it'll work fine.

There is a great 7 step explanation on how this all works on [Android Docs page](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

Answer (score 0):

onPause method does not mean that your Activity is finishing, merely that it is pausing. If the user is pressing the back-button for example it will Pause, but not finish the Activity. better see the Activity lifecycle documentation

and also see this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29